# Passing variables to pkg's pre install script

Tags: macos, installation, pkg-file

Is there a way to install a pkg package, using the installer command line, but setting an environment variable that the pre-script inside the pkg can read while it's being executed?

I need to set an environment variable that the pkg's pre install script can read. Is this possible?

Another approach is more than welcome!

Thanks,
Carlos.